# Setblock any cracked blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to create cracked block like this?:

[image: Cracked block example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

That is not a special version of the block, it is a decal (image) applied to the block while breaking it.

The only block with a cracked texture on it (to my knowledge) is the [Cracked Stone Bricks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cracked_Stone_Bricks)

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, no. If you want this effect in your world, you'll need to do it with a custom texture.